# weak-* topology

Tags: general-topology

What is the definition of weak-*topology ($\sigma(X^*,X)$)? What is the intuition standing behind its definition (apart from easier extraction of finite subcovers - Banach - Alaoglu theorem)?

I start with weak topology. So let $X, Y_j$ be topological spaces and let $f_j\colon X\to Y_j$, $j\in J$. Consider a collection

$$\mathcal{O}=\{\bigcap_{j=1}^k f_{j}^{-1}(O_j)\mbox{-open in}\,X,\, k\in\mathbb{N},\,O_j\, \mbox{open in}\, Y_j\}.\qquad (1)$$ 
The collection $\mathcal{O}$ is closed under finite intersections, so it is a base of a topology on $X$. Such a topology is called the weak topology. The idea which stands behind this definition is simple: we want to obtain a topology which makes all the functions $f_j$ continuous. So the most natural way is to demand that $f^{-1}_j(O_j)$ are open sets and construct the topology via basis. There is also a very nice characterization of weak topology if we assume $X$ to be Hausdorff.

Taking $X$ to be a normed space and $f_j\in X^*$ we have a theorem which gives a view on basis of neighbourhoods of $x_0$ for the weak topology. The sets given by
$$W^{x_{0}}_{f_1,…,f_k,\varepsilon}=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{x\in X\,:\,|f_{j}(x)-f_j(x_{0})|<\varepsilon\}\qquad (2)$$ 
generate the basis of neighbourhoods. So the weak topology in this particular case may by introduced via (2). My intention is to define weak* topology via (3), i.e.,

$$W^{f_{0}}_{x_1,…,x_k,\varepsilon}=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{f\in X^*\,:\,|f(x_j)-f_0 (x_{j})|<\varepsilon\}.\qquad (3)$$
In order to do so, I have to prove that for every weakly* open set $O$ containing $f_{0}$ there exists a set $W$ (at least one) of the form given by (3) such that $W\subset O$. Then I obtain the base of neighbourhoods and as a result the base of topology. But I have to take $O$ being a weak* neighbourhood. So what are the weak* open sets?

Comment: I think you have the correct base for the weak * topology. There you want the minimal topology that makes all point evaluations continuous, and then you have finite intersections of the inverse images of basic open subsets of the reals under those maps.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know it is a base? In order to show that sets given by (2) generate the base of topology, I had to use (1). Now I cannot. Can we do something similar with (3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a normed space $X$ and $\mathcal{F}\subseteq X^*$ let $\sigma(X,\mathcal{F})$ be the smallest topology on $X$ such that all $f\in\mathcal{F}$ become continous (i.e. the intersection over all such topologies).Then a subbasis is given as in (1) and as in (2) of your question  a neighbourhoodbasis of $x_0\in X$ is given by the sets

$$W^{x_{0}}_{f_1,…,f_k,\varepsilon}=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{x\in X\,:\,|f_{j}(x)-f_j(x_{0})|<\varepsilon\} \qquad (2)$$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, $f_j\in \mathcal{F}$ and $\varepsilon>0$.
(Same proof as for $\mathcal{F}=X^*$.)

There is the canonical linear isomorphism $Q: X\to Q(X)\subseteq X^{**},$ $ Q(x)(x^*)=x^*(x)$, so $Q(X)$ is the family of point evaluations. Now the weak* topology on $X^*$ is just the topology $\sigma (X^*,Q(X))$, which one often writes as $\sigma (X^*,X)$ because  $X\cong Q(X)$. By (2) a neighbourhoodbasis for $f_0\in X^*$ is given by the sets

$$W^{f_{0}}_{w_1,…,w_k,\varepsilon}=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{f\in X^*\,:\,|w_{j}(f)-w_j(f_{0})|<\varepsilon\}$$

where $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, $w_j\in Q(X)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. But since $Q$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Q(X)$, this collection of sets is the same as the collection of  sets

$$W^{f_{0}}_{x_1,…,x_k,\varepsilon}=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{f\in X^*\,:\,|Q(x_{j})(f)-Q(x_j)(f_{0})|<\varepsilon\}\\
=\bigcap_{j=1}^k \{f\in X^*\,:\,|f(x_j)-f_{0}(x_j)|<\varepsilon\}$$

where $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, $x_j\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$, which is  exactly (3) in your question.

I hope this brings some clarification! Have fun!

Comment: To the O.P: The intuition behind the weak$^*$ topology is that it is the topology of point-wise convergence of the functions that belong to $X^*.$ That is, a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $X^*$  converges weakly to $f\in X^*$  iff $(f_n(v))_n$ converges to $f(v)$ for each $v\in X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments - now it is clear to me. I didn't notice at first that isomorphism between $X$ and $X^{**}$ can be used.